# How to use Android aapt to compile a specific layout file to binary?

Tags: android, xml

I found something like abrc.sh (https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=785012),  which uses **aapt** to package the project and extract specific files.

What I want to know is whether there is a way to only compile a specific layout file to binary that can be inflate in the Android runtime but not the whole project?

Comment: Why don't you compile it from source?

Comment: maybe this will help https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/08/22/building-android-application-bundles-apks-by-hand/

Comment: @Selvin he asked a clear question, and he already knows how to build from source code.

Comment: You cannot ..... You need to repackage the apk and sign it again...

Comment: Can you approve it? Source?